# Passing a javascript variable to Ruby in a combo box nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, combobox, navigation

**Updated Example**

I am using a Select Box as a nav. When I select an item, I would like to be redirected to that page.

```
= select (@organization, "tabs", @organization.tabs.collect { |t| t.title }, {} { :onchange => "escape_javascript(#{ render edit_organization_tab_path(@organization, this.value)})"} )
```

So this example does not work because I am not sure how to pass a Javascript variable to Ruby

Is it possible to do this entirely in Ruby? Or do I have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can do it with something like this:

```
= select(@organization, "tabs", @organization.tabs.collect { |t| [ t.title, edit_organization_tab_url(t) ] }, { }, :onchange => "window.location.href=$(this).val()")
```

The value for each item in the select list should be the URL you want to redirect the person to.

I'm not sure what you meant by putting a Rails render call inside a JavaScript block.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered how this might degrade if the user does not have JavaScript enabled? Ideally the link elements would still be available as regular `<a/>` elements so a user could still visit a page without JS. Especially since your select box controls site navigation, I'd recommend a "progressive enhancement" solution and write the markup first without JS, then add in JS behavior on top of it. You may want some CSS and `<div/>` elements that resemble a select box but are not literally a select box, this way you have more control over the contents. Couple of other things, as tadman pointed out, redirecting the user in JavaScript boils down to setting `window.location`. If you are using jQuery, check the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) which you can attach to selection events in your combobox, and redirect the user as necessary. Finally, using CSS3 `border-radius` and other properties, you could create something that looks very similar to a select box, but has much more functionality. You could also find a component like this, googling [turned up this example](http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/).

Comment: Simpler answer: return HTML with plain `<a/>` elements (if they are stored on the server, in a DB for example). With jQuery write out a select tag and and `<option/>` elements for each link. Write a click handler the `<option/>` elements and do the redirection there, may need to use a `live` event. Without JavaScript, user just has regular links to click.

Comment: Without javascript disabled, wouldn't they potentially have a corrupted page with a bunch of links spilling out of a broken combo box?

Comment: The HTML only solution is probably just a UL or div with `<a/>` links in it. Then JavaScript rewrites it to be a select box. The reason is because I do not think it is valid to put links inside option elements in a select box, and if you want to serve both scenarios, this would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, but you will need Javascript. Ultimately, you will either need to use (and possibly create) a helper that will create a navigation-ready select box (including the necessary Javascript code) or add event listeners to your select directly in your view (inline or in an included script).

Comment: Updated my ideas above. Appreciate your insight.